# org.hibernate.HibernateException: getNamedQuery is not valid without active transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, hibernate3

**I got an exception:**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: getNamedQuery is not valid without active transaction    org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:340)
    $Proxy10.getNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
```

**Here is my configuration:**

```
    ...
    <context:annotation-driven/>
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>       
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    ...
```

Also, I added `context:annotation-driven` since the `tr:annotation-driven` is not working. Does `<tx:annotation-driven/>` use the `transactionManager` which obtain its own session from Hibernate?

I used my derived `sessionFactory` using Hibernate3 inside the annotated transaction, so how do I configure the Spring to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction manager has a dependency on session factory which it's using to manage transactions.

By adding `<tx:annotation-driven />` you tell Spring how transactions are demarcated. In this case you can use annotations.

See the docs page how to use [XML Schema-based configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html):

> ```xml
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>        xsi:schemaLocation="
> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
>
> <!-- bean definitions here -->
>
> </beans>
> ```

Comment: It's not working for transactions tx, so I added context element and mapping, as well as context:annotation-driven since I got session from hibernate directly,  but no use, still no transaction.

Comment: Update Hibernate libraries to at least Hibernate 4, make sure it's working before using transactions. Also you need `@Transactional` on repositories to demarcate  your transactions.