# Spring configuration and transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I played with this numerous times, changing the default target namespace, still it will complain the context undeclared element: `Multiple annotations found at this line: - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element`  'context:annotation-driven'.

```
    ------Configuration File----
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
<context:annotation-driven/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />     
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>               
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
...
```

Also, I added two annotation-driven since the transaction is not working, does `tx:annotation-driven` use the `transactionManager` which has it's own session from hibernate?

I used my derived sessionFactory using hibernate3, so only need a transactional before the method to run update queries.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873816/how-could-this-spring-configuration-not-working

Comment: Please, add the full configuration file.

Comment: see the top part, others just beans @v.ladynev

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and better use java-based config